# Problems with Django static files

Tags: python, django

I have downloaded this project and trying to make it work: http://sourceforge.net/p/etconf/git/ci/master/tree/

The problem is, after I managed to install all prerequisites, it runs, but does not load staticfiles. According to settings it should look for them in the `/media` directory, but however I tried to change `MEDIA_ROOT`, `STATIC_URL` and various different parameters in `settings.py` it shows in the console:

```
[09/Oct/2015 10:56:08] "GET /static/configurator/admin/css/base.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2281
[09/Oct/2015 10:56:08] "GET /static/configurator/configurator.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2275
[09/Oct/2015 10:56:08] "GET /static/configurator/prototype.js HTTP/1.1" 404 2263
[09/Oct/2015 10:56:08] "GET /static/configurator/configurator.js HTTP/1.1" 404 2272
```

What am I doing wrong? Maybe it's some sort of old bug or something (project is using python 2 and django 1.1)

Comment: static files shouldnot be in /media, they should be in /static,

Comment: and project should be upgraded to latest django, because django1.1 is from 1st century

Comment: @doniyor don't you think I know that? but before i change this project, i want to first run it and see what it looks like to determine if it's woth time updating

Answer (score 0):

I guess you missed to run below command after configuration:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

What I see is you get 404 error for static files which means that the files are not located where it is been searched for.

Comment: They should be searched for in another directory, that is the problem. Also, it seems like Django 1.1 does not support `collectstatic` command

Comment: As per django 1.1 documentation, it search for directory in STATICFILES_DIRS parameter in settings file. Have you configured this, if this could help. Once you are done you can run python manage.py findstatic to verify  what you configured is picked up by django.

Comment: I dunno, but I get this message: `Unknown command: 'collectstatic'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage.`. And when I run `python manage.py help` there is no `collectstatic` command there.

Comment: In django 1.1 it is not available, try findstatic instead of collectstatic.

Comment: nope, not there either. Yet I have another issue now, I probably shoul close this question, as this weird behavior just disappeared